# Passing parameters in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, search, core-data, parameters

Trying to filter (search) through a core data container of people, by name with the letter D in their name. The first code works fine but when you get to passing params in the second code it crashes with a thread 1 sigabrt.

```
class func filterData() -> [Patient]?{

    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Patient> = Patient.fetchRequest()
    var patient:[Patient]? = nil

    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", "D")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do{
        patient = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return patient
    }catch{
        return patient
    }

}

class func filterData(x: String, y: String) -> [Patient]?{

    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Patient> = Patient.fetchRequest()
    var patient:[Patient]? = nil

    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(y) contains[c] %@", "\(x)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do{
        patient = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return patient
    }catch{
        return patient
    }

}
```

The only difference between the two blocks of code is line 1 and 5.

breakpoint indicates crash on line 5 of second block of code

console:

```
2018-05-09 01:08:40.105003-0400 coreDataApp[45029:6524223] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string " contains[c] %@"'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8891e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010672c031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010613e8bd _qfqp2_performParsing + 7771
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010613c9fb +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:arguments:] + 46
    4   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000109e8eaf0 _T0So12NSExpressionC10FoundationEABSS6format_s7CVarArg_pdtcfcTf4xnn_nTm + 112
    5   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000109dee1ff _T0So12NSExpressionC10FoundationEABSS6format_s7CVarArg_pdtcfCTm + 79
    6   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000109dee1a6 _T0So11NSPredicateC10FoundationEABSS6format_s7CVarArg_pdtcfC + 38
    7   coreDataApp                         0x0000000105e1111f _T011coreDataApp04CoreB7HandlerC06filterB0SayAA7PatientCGSgSS1x_SS1ytFZ + 1071
    8   coreDataApp                         0x0000000105e14845 _T011coreDataApp14ViewControllerC6getteryypF + 1493
    9   coreDataApp                         0x0000000105e16781 _T011coreDataApp14ViewControllerC6getteryypFTo + 81
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107516448 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107691804 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107691b21 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107690a69 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 580
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010758b11f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010758c821 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4086
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000107530370 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000107e7157f __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2796
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107e74194 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a82bbb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8104af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a80fa6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a80f30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d234a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001075150b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  coreDataApp                         0x0000000105e19707 main + 55
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bb0a955 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDIT 2: this is how im calling the filterdata() method with params from an alert controller

```
var ruckus = String()
var rico = String()

@IBAction func getter(_ sender: Any) {

    let getter = UIAlertController(title: "Kingdom Search", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    getter.addTextField{ (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "type of search"
    }
    getter.addTextField{ (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "search term"
    }

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Search", style: .default){ (_) in
        let king = getter.textFields!.first?.text!
        let phyl = getter.textFields!.last?.text!
        self.ruckus = king!
        self.rico = phyl!

    }
    getter.addAction(action)
    present(getter, animated: true, completion: nil)

    patient = CoreDataHandler.filterData(x: ruckus, y: rico)
    for i in patient!{
        self.labelshow.text = i.name!
        self.lebelshow.text = i.problem!

    } 

}
```

Comment: Point out the exact line causing the crash and update your question with the complete error message.

Comment: `y` is an empty string and that's why the predicate is invalid.

Comment: updated. line 5 of second method crashes with thread 1: signal sigabrt

Comment: how exactly would I write the formal and actual parameters? im kinda new to swift

Comment: Show how you call this `filterData(x: String, y: String)`. The problem is that you are passing the empty string to the `y` parameter.

Comment: `patient = CoreDataHandler.filterData(x: ruckus, y: rico)`, where `ruckus` and  `rico` are strings from an alert controller. However, before I can enter any strings, it crashes

Comment: @DanielG If it's called before you even enter any strings then put a breakpoint on `filterData(x:y:)` and check the function call stack trace. It's being called from somewhere and it seems it shouldn't be.

Comment: @DanielG Improve your parameter names. What does `x` and `y` signify? Even `ruckus` and `rico` doesn't tell us much. What is it? Firstname and lastname? Finally what is the purpose of `filterData(x:y:)`? I have a feeling your entire predicate is wrong.

Comment: ruckus was going to be the type of search key: name and rico was going to be the value to search: "D". so if I put in my alert controller, name and D for both textfields, it should do a search on the data for all names with D

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string interpolation to build a predicate format string.
For dynamic keys you need the `%K`  format:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K contains[c] %@", key, value)
```

This can still crash if `key` is not the name of a property of that
entity. One can use `#keyPath(Patient.name)` to make the compiler
check and generate the property name.

Comment: where would I use `#keyPath(Patient.name)`

Comment: @DanielG: For example when calling the function: `filterData(x: "D", y: #keyPath(Patient.name))`  – you might want to choose more sensible parameter names though.

Comment: `class func filterData(x: String, y: String) -> [Patient]?{` would be `class func filterData(x: value, y: key) -> [Patient]?{`? and within this method, `var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K contains[c] %@", key, value)`? and when I call the method, `filterData(x: "D", y: #keyPath(Patient.name))`? How would I set the y value from an alert controller if I wanted the value to be Patient.problem?

Comment: @DanielG: Add you alert controller code to the question.

Comment: updated it, but are those chunks of code ^ what I should be putting in?

Comment: @DanielG: If the user can enter arbitrary strings in the "what to search" field then you are out of luck. If the user enters an "invalid" attribute name then the fetch will crash. – It would be better to offer a choice of known attributes from which the user can select one.

Comment: okay, then just use a switch or an if statement to convert the selected attribute string into an actual key?

Comment: @DanielG: That would be an option.

Comment: When I use `class func filterData(x: value, y: key) -> [Patient]?{` I get: "use of undeclared type key" error, also for value. Sorry I'm very new.. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanielG: Nobody said that you should change the declaration from `class func filterData(x: String, y: String) -> [Patient]?`

Comment: im so lost then.. how would key and value be updated for: `var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K contains[c] %@", key, value)`

Comment: @DanielG: Then make it `class func filterData(key: String, value: String) -> [Patient]?`

Comment: okay then call the func: `filterData(key: #keyPath(Patient.name), value: stringyString)` which works finally, but I need to store the key path as a var so that I can make it `#keyPath(Patient.age)`, etc. So that I can call:  `filterData(key: myNewVar, value: stringyString)`.  Im stuck there.